# How do I get a channel for discussion at the Telethon Library?

Tags: python, telethon

Some channels have a link to the chat for discussion. I would like to get them.
[image: discussion chat button]

I searched the library documentation for the word "discuss", but I found no information.
I was hoping to be able to get this information using the `GetFullChannelRequest` function.
For [@mudak](https://t.me/mudak) it worked, but not for [@dvachannel](https://t.me/dvachannel).

```py
ChatFull(full_chat=ChannelFull(
id=1006147755,
"about=""mdk.is \nThe greatest community in Europe ...",
...
"folder_id=None",
linked_chat_id=1067543874,
"location=None",
...
"chats="[
    Channel(id=1006147755,
    "title=""MDK",
    ...
    "participants_count=None)",

    Channel(id=1067543874,
    "title=""MDK CHAT",
    ...
    "participants_count=None)"
],
"users="[
   
])
```

For @dvachannel there is no `linked_chat_id` and `chats` contains only one chat:

```py
ChatFull(full_chat=ChannelFull(
id=1003073997,
"about=""Бред\n\nЛегитимный Абу - @abuwtf\nРазбаны - @Manhattan666 ...",
...
"folder_id=None",
"linked_chat_id=None",
"location=None",
...
"chats="[
   Channel(id=1003073997,
   "title=""Двач",
   ...
   "participants_count=None)"
],
"users="[
   ...
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.
I used `GetFullChannelRequest` incorrectly - I gave it the entity instead of the channel username.

Incorrect use:

```py
chat_entity = await client.get_entity(1003073997)
result = await client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel=chat_entity))
print(result.stringify())
```

Correct use:

```py
result = await client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel='dvachannel'))
print(result.stringify())
```

Comment: The incorrect use is only incorrect because you forgot a minus sign before the ID (marked channel IDs start with `-100`, so `-1003073997`). Both should work fine.